# GmailApp.sendEmail 'from' option not working

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace

I can't get

```
GMailApp.sendEmail('me@mydomain.nl','Subject of this email',Logger.getLog(),
     {name:'Save attachments from triggered attachment script',from:'logging@mydomain.nl'}
```

to actually put the from email address in send emails from my Google Workspace account. All emails from the script have me@mydomain.nl (which is the default address for my domain) as the from email address.

I can send with the logging@mydomain.nl from the Gmailapp without a problem. It is just that within  GAS it doesn't work. I also tried different aliases. Same results.

logging@mydomain.nl is setup as an alias. I tried with both 'treat as an alias' checked and unchecked

Do you have an idea as to what the problem might be?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Peter Berkhout

EDIT:
I copied and pasted the code to the inputbox here and after that I noticed that the G from MailApp was missing so I added the G manually.
Turns out that there also is a function MailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,body,options)...
When I changed my code to GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,body,options) it worked.
So there was no bug, it was me all the time...

recap:

```
MailApp.sendEmail('me@mydomain.nl','Subject of this email',Logger.getLog(),
     {name:'Save attachments from triggered attachment script',from:'logging@mydomain.nl'}
```

doesn't allow the from to be overridden. (It just ignores it)

And

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('me@mydomain.nl','Subject of this email',Logger.getLog(),
     {name:'Save attachments from triggered attachment script',from:'logging@mydomain.nl'}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: is `logging@mydomain.nl` one of your aliases. Is it an element of the string array returned by GmailApp.getAliases().  If it's not then it won't work.  You can go [here](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#settings/accounts) to add another email

Comment: It is one of my aliases and it is in the returned list of GmailApp.getAliases()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue was resolved above, I'm writing this response as a community wiki.

The option to send emails from an alias is within the class `GmailApp`, you can check in the [advanced parameters list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options), you will find the `from` parameter.

> `from` - String - the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by `getAliases()`

The class `MailApp` does not list the `from` parameter, this class has other advanced parameters, which are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters).